# Dropdown toggle should come up if dropdown data goes out of screen

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I am using Angular 8,
If we have 20 dropdowns `<ul>` entries, then dropdown toggle `<ul>` is going out of the screen.

I need to scroll the whole screen to see all the list of dropdown

Screenshot 1: DropDown that has 15 entries, but here I can see only 7 entries, 
If I want to see all 15 entries then I need to scroll whole screen (Screenshot 2)
[image: DropDown that have]

**Screenshot 2:** I need to scroll whole scree to see all data, 

[image]

All I need to scroll only the dropdown till i find the last item or as soon as it goes out of screen, i need that dropdown to up , something like this Screenshot 3

**Screenshot 3:** I need something like this 
[image]

```
@import "~src/assets/styles/bootstrap-theme";
@import "~src/assets/styles/icons";

:host {
  form {
    position: relative;

    &.ng-invalid {
      .dropdown-display {
        border: $text-border-width solid $common-color-error-red;
        background-color: $common-color-error-background;
        z-index: 100; // to make sure the dropdown toggle border is drawn over the barcode button border
      }
    }
  }

  div.background {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1031;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }

  div.dropdown.disabled {
    .form-control {
      background-color: $input-disabled-bg;
    }
    .input-group-append button, .input-group-append .input-group-text {
      background-color: $input-disabled-bg;
    }
  }

  div.dropdown .dropdown-display {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  ul.dropdown-menu {
    max-height: 50vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    z-index: 1040;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }

  ul.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    &:hover {
      color:$common-color-white;
    }

    &.highlight-selection {
      background-color: $highlight-input-background;
      color: $highlight-input-text-color;
    }
  }

  ul.dropdown-menu > li > input {
    padding: 3px 15px; // px values since this is dependent on bootstrap, which also uses px for this
    background-color: white;
  }

  ul.tags {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border: $text-border-width solid darken($light-input-background, 5%);

    li {
      flex: 0 0 auto;
      background-color: $light-input-background;
      padding: 0.3125rem;
      margin: 0.3125rem;
    }
  }

  .input-group-append {
    button {
      padding-top: 0.0625rem;
      padding-bottom: 0;
      color: $primary;
      background-color: $secondary;
      border-color: $secondary;
    }
    .input-group-text {
      background-color: $secondary;
      border-color: $secondary;
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="background " *ngIf="showDropdownMenu" (click)="toggleDropdown()"></div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="form-control flex-grow-1 dropdown-display"
                 (click)="toggleDropdownFromMenu($event)">
                {{ model.selectedEntry}}
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-append" *ngIf="model.options.scannable">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary"
                        type="button"
                        (click)="doScan($event)">
                    <fa-icon [icon]="faBarcode" size="2x"></fa-icon>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-append"
                 (click)="toggleDropdownFromMenu($event)">
                <fa-icon [icon]="faCaretDown" class="input-group-text"></fa-icon>
            </div>
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </div>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu " role="menu" [ngClass]="{ show: showDropdownMenu }">
            <li role="menuitem">
                <input type="text"
                       formControlName="searchInput"
                       *ngIf="model.value.length > 3"
                       (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                       class="form-control"
                       [placeholder]="strings.searchPlaceholder"
                >
            </li>
            <li role="menuitem"
                *ngFor="let entry of searchMatchingEntries">
                <a class="dropdown-item"
                   (click)="onSelected(entry)"
                   [ngClass]="{'highlight-selection':isSelected(entry)}">{{entry.displayName}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: A minimal working example (eg using Stackblitz) would be easier to try to solve the issue.

Comment: we have used many customs directives, if I need to code in fiddle then I need to add everything. 
can you help something by seeing screenshot..or advice me css how to use to overcome above Screenshot 2, whole screen is scrolling up instead of just dropdown. 

Or an example or link : If it reaches to end of screen then i want to show dropdown list upside instead of down. Any help please

Comment: That's why it's called a *minimal working example*. Since this is a pure HTML and CSS problem, you could strip out the non-essential parts and use some sample data to reproduce the issue. The customs directives would be irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: will try ..give me some time